# Multiple locale file lookup in Django

Tags: python, django, localization

In my Django app i have the usual `django.po` locale file under each of the languages. However, I'd like to create a custom locale file called `custom.po`. Is there any way I could Django to first check for a translation string in the `custom.po` file and if it doesn't exist, check the `django.po` file

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths) setting. This tuple is order-specific, so if you put the path to your `custom.po` first, you will achieve the effect you're after.

**Edit**: Additional link for detailed information about [How Django discovers translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations).

Comment: Hi Jakub, this looks like a very promising approach to all my current Django problems. In some view I need to LOCALE_PATHS to be different. Could you tell me how I could modify the `LOCALE_PATH` at a view level? i.e. change the settings on the fly. I know that switching settings on the fly is a a bad idea but it would save me a lot of extra work. Thanks.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to modify global settings and guarantee it works as expected. After taking a brief look at translation code, it looks like it would be risky to do (judging by function caching which is done in there - I might be wrong, though). If you really need to separate "normal" string from those "external", you could try adding a prefix for their IDs or something. Unless, you don't use IDs, in which case it won't work.